# Prestashop module back office tab opens iframe

Tags: php, iframe, module, admin, prestashop

I am creating a prestashop 1.6 module.  In the back office it creates a root tab and 4 child tabs.  Each child tab has it's own controller which I have made and is all set up.

What I would like to do is have each of the child tab's controllers open an iframe in the back office.  I would like the back office to wrap the iframe so it appears native like the typical prestashop back office forms.  Is there a way to do this?  I have done a lot of googling and nothing I have found has worked.  Hoping someone here knows a solution!

[image]

Comment: In your admin module tpl add your iframe code, you can see the tpl admin forms in admin/themes/default/template/controllers

Comment: @tarekfellah how do I assign that template to my controller so that when the controller for that tab gets loaded my .tpl get displayed?  Is there a method that I need to override in my controller in order to display a .tpl instead of a form?

Comment: i think you can ues createTemplate($tpl_name) in the admin controller

Comment: @tarekfellah what do I do after I call $this->createTemplate('test.tpl') ?  Prestashop documentation doesn't explain any of this.

Comment: try to add after creteTemplate return $template->fetch("test.tpl"); 
if it doesn't work, try to remplace the 2 insctructions with return $this->smartyOutputContent('test.tpl');